# Day and month incorrect when setting next day of date using Calendar

Tags: java, date, calendar, date-format

```
//fetch date and convert to date type
String DateString = Integer.toString(getDay()) + "/" + Integer.toString(getMonth()) + "/" + Integer.toString(getYear());
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //current format of date
Date date = (Date) parser.parse(DateString); //convert string to date
//calculate next day
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date); //set calendar time to chosen date
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); //add 1 day to calendar date
//set object to next day
parser.format(cal.getTime()); //set format to dd/MM/yyyy
setDay(cal.get(cal.DAY_OF_MONTH));
setMonth(cal.get(cal.MONTH));
setYear(cal.get(cal.YEAR));
```

I set a date to 23 October 2002. I want to set it to the next day using the above method. It shows 24 September 2002 instead of 24 October 2002. Why is it adding 1 to the day and removing 1 from the month?

Comment: Are you aware that months are zero based on Date?

Comment: It's a stupid design decision. January is month 0 instead of month 1, February is 1 instead of 2 and so on...

Comment: ["*A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.*"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) reading the documentation is good for you.

Comment: That days are counted starting from 1 but months are counted starting from 0.
First day is 1, but first month (January) is 0.

Comment: If java 8, consider the types in the `java.time` package. If not, consider joda time. There's _far less_ surprises in these date and time APIs.

Comment: +1: I think it's entirely reasonable that the OP assumed that January has value 1. The International Standards Organisation defines it as 1 which is good enough for me. For some reason, Java bases it at 0. I guess it comes from the old C array days.

Comment: @Bathsheba:- Yes thats true the tm structure (defined in time.h) has an integer field tm_mon with the (commented) range of 0-11.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that months are zero based index ie, they start from 0 instead of 1 so January is 0, Feb is 1, march is 2 and .....Decemeber is 11

From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date()):

> A month is represented by an integer from 0 to 11; 0 is January, 1 is
>   February, and so forth; thus 11 is December.

**EDIT:-**

Trying to give the reason for why months start with zero.
The `tm` structure which is defined in `time.h` has an integer field `tm_mon` with the range of 0-11, so I guess this has been taken from the C language. One other reason which might sound wierd but can be reason that since we have names of the month but for days(1,2,3...30,31) we dont have any names